# Where to place custom opencart extension

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have started working with opencart. I am not sure where to place custom extension that I want to build. 
Will it goes with the core /admin/ and /catalog/ directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the contents inside root. If it already has the directory structure implemented, The files will go automatically where they are meant to be.

For further knowledge, please go through

http://docs.opencart.com/extension/installer/